# CCLabelTTF UILineBreakModeWordWrap doesn't work for custom font

Tags: ios, fonts, cocos2d-iphone

I am using couple of custom fonts in my project. When I use Bookman, line break works fine but when I switch to Myriad Pro, it stops working. Basically the text is shown in one large single line. Even the \n doesn't work either. Any suggestions?

```
textSize = [text2 sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"myriadprosemibold" size:24.0f]
                     constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.contentSize.width/2, 2000)
                         lineBreakMode:CCLineBreakModeWordWrap];


label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:content
                                 dimensions: textSize
                                  alignment: alignment
                                   fontName:font
                                   fontSize:size];

        [label setColor:color];
        [self addChild:label z:1];
```

Note: I have got the Myriad pro as OTF and converted it to TTF

Update: I have noticed that textSize is coming as 0,0. So it is going wrong in calculation. For now, I have hardcoded the size since the text is not dynamic but any suggestion?

Comment: Where are you using textSize?  The size that gets supplied to CCLabelTTF is just the pixel size that you would like to apply.

Comment: Corrected the variable name, was trying multiple combinations didn't realized this snippet had different variable name. Corrected it now.

Comment: Ok, looks like getting the dynamic size just won't work for an imported font, but you could try using a different font, of a similar style, in the size calculation: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/10384

Comment: Yes but what I wonder here is that Bookman is also an imported font and this problem doesnt arise when I use it. The suggestion you have given should work with a good accuracy though, but what would I want to understand is the reason for failure of this particular font. Is there something in conversion of OTF to TTF?

Comment: Good point.  Could be the conversion, not sure to be honest.  You could try to download a 'fresh' Myriad Pro TTF from somewhere.  Alternatively there's a MyriadWebPro.ttf included with Lion you could try - it looks a bit less subtle than the original but is reasonably similar.